# How to search and return document name in Marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How can I search contents of documents and return the corresponding document name in Marklogic? Suppose my document name is `test.doc` and it contains a text **e.g "hello world"**. Now I am uploading this document in Marklogic Server and the content processor will generate the corresponding XML files. Now I am searching like this:-

```
import module namespace search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/Marklogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";
declare variable $options:=
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<transform-results apply="raw"/>
</options>;

for $d in search:search("hello world", $options)/search:result
return tokenize(data($d/@uri), "/")[last()]
```

It returns the corresponding XML and XHTML file names containing the text "**hello world**" but I want to return only the original document name (`test.doc`) not the corresponding XML file name.

Comment: What version of MarkLogic are your running, and which content processor do you have enabled?

Comment: I am using Marklogic 5.0-2 Enterprise Edition and I have content processor enabled for office 2007/2010 documents.

Answer (score 1):

Might be out of date, but useful.

http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-uri

```
xdmp:node-uri

xdmp:node-uri(
   $node as node()
) as xs:string?
Summary
```

Returns the `document-uri` property of the parameter or its ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not retained automatically, so you need to somehow explicitly support it in your content pipeline.

You can modify the pipeline to store the original document name in a document property for the destination XML document, you could store the document name as metadata in the document, or you could store the original document name as part of the URI.